# How to re-create the AES encryption method if I only have the decryption method

Tags: java, encryption

I would like to know if it's possible to come re-produce the encryption process only from decryption method?

In others words, I've got this code and I want to go back to encryption.

```
public class Encrypter {
    private String iv           = "qj839.SkW@a#pPsX";
    private String SecretKey    = "!D&@DKmq81-CClo";
    String keyphrase = "SomeWords";

    private IvParameterSpec ivspec;
    private SecretKeySpec keyspec;
    private Cipher cipher;

    public Encrypter() {
        SecretKey = Hash.getMD5(keyphrase).substring(4, 20);
        ivspec = new IvParameterSpec(iv.getBytes());
        keyspec = new SecretKeySpec(SecretKey.getBytes(), "AES");
        try {
            cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/NoPadding");
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (NoSuchPaddingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public byte[] decrypt(String code) throws Exception {
        if (code == null || code.length() == 0) {
            return null;
        }

        code = code.replaceAll("-", "").toLowerCase();
        byte[] decrypted = null;
        try {
            cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, keyspec, ivspec);
            decrypted = cipher.doFinal(hexToBytes(code));
            //Remove trailing zeroes
            if (decrypted.length > 0) {
                int trim = 0;
                for (int i = decrypted.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
                    if (decrypted[i] == 0) {
                        trim++;
                    }
                }

                if (trim > 0) {
                    byte[] newArray = new byte[decrypted.length - trim];
                    int length = decrypted.length - trim;
                    int srcPos = 0;
                    int destPos = 0;
                    while (length > 0) {
                        newArray[destPos] = decrypted[srcPos];
                        srcPos++;
                        destPos++;
                        length--;
                    }
                    decrypted = newArray;
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return null;
        }
        return decrypted;
    }

    public String decryptString(String text) throws Exception {
        byte[] temp = decrypt(text);
        if (temp == null) return null;
        return new String(temp);
    }

    public byte[] hexToBytes(String str) {
        if (str == null) {
            return null;
        } else if (str.length() < 2) {
            return null;
        } else {
            int len = str.length() / 2;
            byte[] buffer = new byte[len];
            for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
                buffer[i] = (byte) Integer.parseInt(str.substring(i * 2, i * 2 + 2), 16);
            }
            return buffer;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Since this is symmetric encryption with AES, the `Encryptor` actually stays the same. I suspect you're not understanding the reason why there is additional code after the line

```
decrypted = cipher.doFinal(hexToBytes(code));
```

which is the actual decryption.

AES in CBC mode works only on a multiple of the block size which is 16 byte for AES. If you want to encrypt plaintext of arbitrary length, you need to pad the plaintext until the expected length is reached. Normally this is done with PKCS#5/PKCS#7 padding, but in this case it's a Zero Padding. It means that the padding is actually 0 to 15 trailing 0x00 bytes.

By specifying the padding as "NoPadding", the developer has the task to implement the padding.

The decryption code is a little clumsy and redundant, but it works.

The code would be something like:

```
/**
 * TODO: add error handling
 */
public String encrypt(byte[] plaintext) {
    int bs = cipher.getBlockSize();
    int targetSize = plaintext.length + (bs - plaintext.length % bs) % bs;
    byte[] plaintextPadded = new byte[targetSize];
    System.arraycopy(plaintext, 0, plaintextPadded, 0, plaintext.length);

    cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, keyspec, ivspec);
    byte[] encrypted = cipher.doFinal(plaintextPadded);
    return bytesToHex(encrypted);
}

// TODO: add bytesToHex implementation
```

This code uses the fact that `new byte[x]` actually initializes all bytes with 0x00, so there is no need to explicitly write the padding bytes.

---

#### Other considerations:

- Zero Padding as used here is can only be used for String data or generally data that can never end in 0x00 bytes. If you want to encrypt arbitrary data, you need to use `Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding")`.
- Never use a static IV. It should be randomly generated for each encryption under the same key. Since it doesn't have to be secret, you can simply prepend it to the ciphertext so that it can be sliced off during decryption.
- An AES key is supposed to be composed of arbitrary bytes. If you restrict the key space to printable characters (`String`), it will be much easier to brute-force. (Not that it is easy to begin with)
- You're using `new String(byte[])` and `string.getBytes()` without additional parameters. You need to pass an additional parameter to both in order to specify the character encoding such as "UTF-8". If you don't then you might run into problems when trying to decrypt a ciphertext which was encrypted on a different system with a different default character set.

Comment: Great answer as usual, Artjom. A bit of a shame about the `/ 16` though, should be `% cipher.getBlockSize()` (it's night, my vision is at its best :P)

Comment: Of course ... Thanks! I know the owl is watching over me ;)

Comment: @MaartenBodewes Should not it be `int targetSize = ((plaintext.length + (cipher.getBlockSize()-1))/cipher.getBlockSize())*cipher.getBlockSize();` instead?

Comment: Are you sure yours code works? For plaintext length `2` it gives `2 + 2 % 8` that is `4`, which is _not block aligned_...

Comment: sorry, for the AES the block size is 16, but the problem is the same

Comment: @vlp you're right. It didn't work. I don't know what I was thinking. Apparently nothing :|